# How to get php-worker to log to stdout / stderr

Tags: stdout, stderr

I want to get logs to stdout/stderr,and I have config on logging.php like this:

```
'stdout' => [
        'driver' => 'monolog',
        'level' => 'debug',
        'handler' => StreamHandler::class,
        'formatter' => LineFormatter::class,
        'formatter_with' => [
            'format' => env('LOG_STDOUT_FORMATTER', "%channel%: %level_name%: %message% %context% %extra%\n"),
            'dateFormat' => '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        ],
        'with' => [
            'stream' => 'php://stdout',
        ],
    ],
```

And then run *docker logs <container_id>*. It return logs from php-fpm (controller) normally.
But can't get log from php-worker (job).
I also try to add stdout_logfile but it isn't work:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=8
user=laradock
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

Please help me if you have any suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

Just show running scheduled command:

> Running scheduled command: '/usr/local/bin/php' 'artisan' test >
> '/dev/null' 2>&1

To show debug log on the command, instead of using

```
$schedule->command();
```

I used

```
$schedule->call(function() {})
```

It will show logs successfully, but I don't know why it works. So I write down the answer here for those who have the same issue as me.